# How to accurately measure a variable resistor?

Tags: current, resistors, adc, embedded, variable

I need to get a measurement from a variable resistor, ranging from 10-180 Ω. Measurement shall be better than 1% over a room temperature ranging from 5 to 45°C. This variable resistor is activated by a mechanism. The  measurement is performed in an embedded µC.

Available power supplies are: 5 V from a DC-DC buck convertor and 3.3 V from an LDO (which is powered from the buck 5 V). Also available an ADC powered from 3.3 V.
I would like to limit the current as much as possible in the variable resistor as well as span the measurement over the 3.3 V of the ADC, therefore constant current source (or sink) fits the requirement (based on TVL431, LM 4041 sink or based on LM4041-N source). A current of 3.3/180= 17 mA is ideal as it gives a voltage range from 170 mV to 3 V at an ADC input (3.3 V powered). Unfortunately, the constant current source leaves little voltage headroom with the available power supplies and I did not find a reasonably simple schematic for implementing the constant current source with the available power supplies. Did I miss something?

Another (basic) solution consists in inserting a 100 Ω (to limit current when the variable resistor is down to 10 Ω) in series with the variable resistor and measure the voltage at the variable resistor end. This is much simpler but the current consumption (assuming powered from the 3.3 V LDO) can be up to 33 mA (100+10 Ω). Another drawback is that the variation in voltage at the variable resistor end will not span the full range of the ADC input due to the 100 Ω resistor.

What would be your recommendation as cost effective schematics for achieving such kind of measurement in an embedded µC?

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Please draw a schematic. I can't tell for sure from your text, but you probably just need a voltage divider with your variable resistor being one of the elements.

Comment: Low-end digital multimeters often display **ohms** with +/- 1% accuracy. It shouldn't be difficult to find a higher-quality multimeter having better accuracy than 1%.

Comment: does the variable resistor have repeatability better than 1%?

Comment: @jsolata: yes it has.

Comment: @all: I added a schematics as required. Also this measurement is performed in an embedded µC, which I master. Only the power supplies (5 V unregulated, 3.3 V regulated) are already built, I cannot change them.

Comment: What else will the resistor be doing?  It's not hard to measure the value of a variable resistor in isolation, but it may be a good deal harder if the resistor is being used for something else simultaneously.

Comment: 1% of 10Ω is only 100mΩ. assuming you mean 1% of span or full scale, it's more like 1.7Ω or 1.8Ω. If the rheostat is remote you and/or if the ground is used for other things (as in an automotive or similar application) you may need more wires for a Kelvin connection or similar arrangement, **particularly** if you try to operate at low current and the ground is used to conduct high currents from other loads.

Comment: @spehro Pefhany. Yes the reostat (variable resistor) is remote, approximately 0.5-1m away. Environment is noisy, due to a PWM controlled brush motor (12 V, 10 A). Is is important to have a good accuracy halfway (in the 50-130 Ohms section)

Comment: @AutoPilot Have you considered using a [rotary encoder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotary_encoder) instead of a pot?

Comment: @AndrewMorton. Yes, incremental encoder is an option. So far, due to mechanical integration and waterproofing, pot was easier and cheaper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thought was to use a classic 3-terminal linear adjustable regulator as a current source, like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7FNLx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For a regulator with internal reference of 1.25V, it also has to have a drop-out voltage less than \$5V - 3.3V - 1.25V = 0.45V\$. Ideally the adjustment pin current \$I_{ADJ}\$ should be as small as possible, very small compared to the current through R1, which would be \$I_{OUT}=\frac{1.25V}{R1}=18mA\$.

By setting \$I_{OUT}=18mA\$, you have a voltage across your variable resistance R2 between 0.18V and 3.24V.

Such a regulator might be hard to find and source, so I came up with this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVvk1q.png)</sup>

The op-amp needs to be a model whose output can reach close to the positive supply, and whose input voltage range includes +80mV above the negative supply. Don't try this with 741, LM358, LM324 or TL0x1, none of them fit the bill. Look for rail-to-rail output, and input voltage range which includes the negative rail, like the TLC227x.

This circuit is another current source, using an op-amp to regulate by maintaining \$V_X = V_{REF}\$. Therefore current \$I\$ down the chain R2  + R1 is:

$$ I = \frac{V_{REF}}{R_1} = \frac{80mV}{4.7\Omega} = 17mA $$

The voltage \$V_{OUT}\$ at the top of R2, being measured is therefore:

$$ V_{OUT} = 80mV + I\cdot R_2 $$

The 80mV offset you'll have to remove in software, but if R2 ranges from 10Ω to 180Ω, then you can expect \$0.25V \le V_{OUT} \le 3.14V\$.

Obviously you'll need an 80mV source. If you trust your 5V supply, then a simple resistor potential divider will do the trick, otherwise a TL431 will work well:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fY7ZeE.png)</sup>

A word of warning: If the variable resistance becomes higher than 180Ω, such as the wiper of a pot momentarily lifting off the track, by riding over dust, for example, then both the above designs will become a very low impedance source of well over 3.3V, which will damage the ADC. The ADC will probably have input protection diodes, to mitigate this, but they'll have some maximum current limit, so I advise the use of a resistor between OUT and the ADC input. For instance:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXemCZ.png)</sup>

---

User Tim Williams suggests in his answer the most simple solution, which I'll illustrate here. If you go with this solution, please accept his answer, not mine. I'm just putting a picture to his words.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAX7Db.png)</sup>

You can use any op-amp whose inputs and output include the negative supply. The relationship between R2 and \$V_{OUT}\$ is:

$$ V_{OUT} = 5\frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2}\left(1+\frac{R_3}{R_4}\right) $$

or

$$ R_2 = \frac{R_1V_{OUT}}{5\left(1+\frac{R_3}{R_4}\right)-V_{OUT}} $$

Using the resistor values shown, as R2 varies from 10Ω to 180Ω, \$V_{OUT}\$ goes from 0.21V to 3.28V, and the above relationship simplifies to:

$$ R_2 = \frac{1000V_{OUT}}{21.5-V_{OUT}} $$

---

If you require the sensor resistor R2 to be physically located far from the amplifier circuitry then you should mitigate noise coupled into the connecting wires by implementing differential signalling. Here's an approach which balances the impedance to DC of each sensor wire, so that noise pickup is (theoretcially) equal in each, and uses an instrumentation amplifier to restore a single-ended signal:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkPP8h.png)</sup>

With no resistor between RG+ and RG−, the IA has gain 5, and therefore performs \$5 \times (V_A - V_B)\$. The subtraction operation cancels noise. I've never used this IA before, but if I've understood the [AD8223 datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD8223.pdf) correctly, I believe this circuit should behave like:

$$ V_{OUT} = 5 \times  \frac{(+5V) \times R_2}{2 \times 600 + R_2} $$

$$ R_2 = \frac{1200\times V_{OUT}}{25-V_{OUT}} $$

This yields \$0.20V \le V_{OUT} \le 3.26V\$ for \$10\Omega \le R_2 \le 180\Omega\$.

C1 attenuates RF and any sharp edges produced by potentiometer motion and motor transients.

With common mode voltages cancelled, your chief concern becomes currents induced magnetically in the connecting wires, which you mitigate by twisting them together, and routing them well away from the motor current loop. Also keep the motor current loop area to a minimum, by running motor power wires as close and parallel to each other as possible, and as far from signal wiring as you can.

Comment: Solution with the TLC2272 and the 4.7Ω is smart. I am balancing complexity vs accuracy. Especially in a noisy environment with a #50cm distance between the PCB and the resistor, as mentioned to @Julien in a comment to his post.

Comment: Would Tim Williams suggestion withstand harsh environment (PWM driving a brush motor 12V 10 A), as the current is low and signal is afterward amplified ? I am thinking about noise !

Comment: @AutoPilot Probably not. I've appended an approach using differential signalling and a differential amplifier to mitigate noise.

Answer (score 0):

Your proposed method is good, simple and reliable for your requirements.

Using a series resistor and reading the voltages across both the series resistor and the variable resistor alternatingly, makes the measurement independent of the supply voltage.

You only need to get a reasonably stable series resistor, so it will have less than 10000 ppm per 40 K drift - i.e. less than 250ppm/K drift which applies for virtually every commercial resistor.

One other error that you should take seriously is the voltage reading offset, which can be tackled by calibration. In general, calibration should be always considered when there are *any* accuracy targets.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd advise him to take under great consideration CMRR since his signal shouldn't be high frequency. The rejection will be most likely done by digital filters.

Comment: @Julien you are right an op-amp would have to have perhaps less than 60 dB CMRR at DC, pretty unlikely these days.

Comment: PSRR will be more important than CMRR, and maybe a real issue with a remote variable resistor.  Servoing the bridge power supply with a \$V_\text{{sense}}\$ might be important.

Answer (score 0):

Use the bottom circuit (resistor divider), but with a large value resistor that approximates a constant current.  Supply it from whatever the ADC's VREF is supplied from (3.3V VCC for example, or it may be an external reference as such; internal reference is okay too, if it is available on an external pin).

Then use an amplifier like [LMV321](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmv321.pdf) in the *noninverting amplifier* configuration, to boost the signal up to ADC level.

This does two things:

1. Minimal current consumption and sensor dissipation (down to a few mA, say; even lower is possible with a micropower precision type amp, and periodic sampling if applicable).
2. Ratiometric measurement: the ADC reading depends only upon the relative resistance values (including the two in the amplifier!).

The system can also be calibrated in software, using a two-point measurement, if manufacturing errors should be removed.

An op-amp also affords differential sensing capability, if that should be helpful (say, if you don't have control over where the sensor ground connects relative to circuit ground).  And if so, a three-wire measurement may be desirable, which will be more complex, and may require more op-amps (in which case an LMV358 or etc. would do).

Filtering components may also be desirable between the sensor and receiver circuit, depending on ambient noise levels, ESD potential, ground-lift surge, etc..

Comment: I am not sure to understand "with a large value resistor". I prepared a schematics to clarify, how can I insert this schematics in the comment ?

Comment: The 180 Ω is integrated in a waterproof casing, I cannot change it. Did I understand you correctly: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UY2r.png)

Comment: Yes, like that!

Answer (score 0):

When you want to get good accuracy, you need to consider many factors, such as noise, temperature drift, nominal tolerance, drift over time, etc. The design you suggest doesn't give enough infos to conclude whether or not this design will perform properly.

You will most likely want an amplifier. The greater the span of the signal, the cheapest will be your amplifier. The most sensitive your design need to be, the harder it will be to design the amplifier. Your use case is important to take a proper decision.

From my experience, the best preforming circuit was to use an integrated front end. It is expensive, but it's all inclusive and worth it. Other development I have made were much more elaborated and performed very well. For instance, one designed use the resistor in the Howland current pump configuration. This allowed for a much lower biasing current and allowed for a lower impact of the input offset bias. For low accuracy solution, I often go with a simple Wheatstone bridge and differential amplifier. This usually give the simplest design. It's not power efficient, but it gives a great accuracy without a lot of work.

Design without amplifier won't yield good results in general. The impedance of the ADC might influence your circuit, the dynamic range of the ADC will be halved and their is no noise rejection at all. The AC characteristics aren't as well documented and your code might affect the accuracy of your measurement.

**Here are some pitfalls you might want to consider:**

- Constant voltage source generally offers better accuracy over longer
  wires then constant current solution (pickup less noise).
- The lower the current, the harder it is to measure the signal. But
  stronger the current, the stronger the self heating. Usually, for
  precision resistance network try to keep your resistors at 1/10th of
  their rated dissipated power.
- All resistance drift differently. A Wheatstone bridge can be a good
  approach to both reduce noise and thermal dependency.
- The input offset of your amplifier will have a significant impact on
  your signal. If you can lower the sampling rate, chopper amplifier
  will give you usually a better accuracy.
- No matter the nominal accuracy, to guarantee any accuracy, you will
  need some type of calibration over time.
- The noise in your analog rail will have a direct impact on your
  performance, even more significant if you measure small variation.
- Those design have a lot of subtilties. You might want to hire a
  consultant for design review. They will save you a lot of iteration!

Comment: A Whestone brige then an AO, as [here](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sloa034/sloa034.pdf) ?

Comment: The position (value) of the resistor is sampled at 30Hz, What do you mean by "chopper amplifier will give you usually a better accuracy" ?

Comment: With a Wheatstone bridge, I would advise you to use an instrumentation amplifier instead of an operational amplifier.

Comment: A chopper amplifier is an amplifier that automatically correct it's differential input offset. This topology as a very low bandwidth. You can check the EEVblog, there is a great video about it.

Comment: Also a Wheatstone bridge shall be [linearised](https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/how-to-linearize-wheatstonebridge-circuit-for-better-performance.html), which adds some complexity. I learned a lot with your post, in the process of balancing the complexity vs benefits according to my knowledge level. Again, environment is noisy (PWM brush motor 50cm nearby 12V 10A). Can the variable resistor be located 50cm away for the Wheatstone bridge or shall it be close to the bridge and front amps ?

Comment: Accuracy comes at a cost! Usually, linearization is done by software since it's predictable. and repeatable. So don't worry to much about it. Just calibrate your system with 10 resistance value and you should be good. Noise is an other thing. You can reduce it with several technique like oversampling and digital filter. But minimizing it in hardware is worth it. To minimize noise, differential pair helps a lot. Impedance should be kept low, and signal should be as large as possible. Keep your trace as short as possible and the closer your bridge is to your sensing element, the better.